# MVC3 razor Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'submit': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I am getting this error when I click my submit button

*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'submit': object is null or undefined*

Here is my submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="saveCommand" value="Save" />
```

and this is the script

```
 $("#btnSave").live('click', function (event) {
                        $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
                    });
```

Any comments on why I am getting this error ?How to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$("#btnSave").live('click', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Also `.live()` is deprecated. If you are using jQuery 1.7 you should use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$('form').on('click', '#btnSave', function() { 
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Also what's the point of using javascript to subscribe to the `.click` event of a `submit` button and submit the containing form? That's what a submit button is intended to do => submit the form in which this button belongs. Or maybe this submit button is not inside a form? This would explain why you are getting the error => the `closest` selector returns nothing and there's nothing to submit.

Comment: I am afraid from the level of information you provided in your question I don't see how I can tell you why it is not hitting your action. As I said in my answer: if there's no containing form for this submit button the `$(this).closest('form')` selector returns `Nothing`. So nothing happens. You cannot expect to submit a form that doesn't exist. Please debug your javascript code: `alert($(this).closest('form').length);`. What do you see?

Comment: $(this).closest('form').submit(); worked for me. thank you for your quick response.